# Is there a way to download all the questions and answers from stack overflow?

Tags: web-scraping, information-extraction

I'm interested at looking at website usage, question types, and answers on stack overflow.  Is there a way to download all of the content?

I've considered web scraping with beautiful soup or similar as an option, but thought that there are so many expert users the information might be readily available through an API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you guess, there's a JSON API, check https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/stack-exchange-api-v2-1/

To get all the questions by example : https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions

It require a programmatic browser and a JSON parser. It's quite simple with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [python](/questions/tagged/python) or [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby).

Another solution proposed by [fvu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112079/fvu) in the comments is to parse a [full snapshot of any stackexchange site](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)

Comment: That's not soup, but it sure is beautiful.  Thanks!

Comment: Better still, there's a complete dump [available for download](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)