# Is there a way to download the links to all the answers by a specific user

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I want to download the links of all the answers by a specific user on Stackoverflow. I am **not familiar** with networking and Javascript. But i am used to working with C++ and Python. So i want to know how can i download the links to all the answers by a specific user on SO programatically using any programming language. That is, any language can be used like javascript, python, C++ etc.

Basically i want to download the links to all answers that i have answered on SO programatically and *looking for a working example*. I am tagging this question with multiple languages since using a particular language is not a requirement. I haven't tried coding it myself since i don't even know how/where to start.

Comment: Quite a broad question, i'd recommend having a play with beautiful soup since you already know Python and then try and make a more specific question once you've gotten to grips with that. https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/

Comment: SO has an API https://api.stackexchange.com/ and a data explorer https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/218381/all-answers-for-user-x although I'm not sure you can get links in the data explorer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to download all the questions and answers from stack overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670229/is-there-a-way-to-download-all-the-questions-and-answers-from-stack-overflow) and /or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176293/how-do-i-export-my-questions-and-answers

Comment: @JonSG No that does not answer my question. I read that post before posting my question. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation available on this page:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users

The user ids can be retrieved from the user's stackoverflow profile page.
To run this programatically you will likely need to get an access token.
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

For example the  Rest API call would look something like this:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/**USER_ID**/answers?key=**SOME_KEY**((&site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default

> Also you can specify multiple users at once.